# Enable Firefox video player full screen mode as default mode for other applications

Tags: macos, fullscreen

Videos in Firefox when made fullscreen do not create a new space, but rather sit on the same desktop as other content. Is there a way to make this happen by default for all windows in macOS? I assume that this would have to be through the command line.

MacBook Air, 2017
macOS Monterey 12.5
Firefox 104.0.1

Answer (score 3):

Firefox uses a JS based fullscreen mode as opposed to the native MacOS fullscreen mode apparently. The result is it looks and "feels" different.

What you can change, is the "feel" of the fullscreen video modes in Firefox. The result of this change is the full screen video will become it's own space in Mission Control, and you can 4 finger gesture between the spaces, hover to see the top menu, etc. This is what you expect of a fullscreen video in either Chrome or Safari.

You'll need to

1. Navigate into your about:config (type that into the URL bar of Firefox, click past the warning)
2. Uncheck the "Show only modified preferences" option
3. Search for "full-screen-api.macos-native-full-screen"
4. Toggle option to true

[image: FireFox Configurations]

There should be no need for a browser refresh and you'll notice the difference upon the next video you expand to full screen. Also the dialog text "website has entered fullscreen" can't be changed which bothers me also.

Comment: I was not asking how to disable this feature, but asking if it is possible to replicate it throughout the rest of macOS

Answer (score 0):

1. In a new tab, type or paste `about:config` in the address bar and press Enter/Return. Click the button promising to be careful.
2. In the search box above the list, type or paste `full-s` and pause while the list is filtered
3. Double-click the `full-screen-api.macos-native-full-screen` preference and double click on that to make it value is true.